# sql transaction log backup theory

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, transactions

The more I look into the transaction log the more I get confused. I think a lot of people get this wrong. I just want to make sure I understand the theory. Please correct my thinking if it's wrong.

The log has nothing to do with Full or Diff backups (No tied or related in any way). The log contains all changes to the database since the last log backup. Hence the log chain. As you make changes to the database, a copy is placed in the log and marked when it's committed to the database. I like to think of it as a full history of all changes since the beginning of time. It gets cleared out when you backup the transaction log (LOG). A continuous stream/record of changes.

*Yes, the log chain starts with the very first full backup ever created. But any fulls after don't reset the log chain.*

1. Load to memory part of the database that is going to be modified
2. Copy change/query into transaction log
3. Make change to the loaded part in memory
4. Commit to disk and checkpoints the log

Full-**log**-log-log-log

Let's say you make a full backup. Then log backups after. The first log will contain changes that were committed before the full backup. It's just the nature of logs. Again, logs aren't related in any way to full or diffs. I assume when you restore the full then the logs after, it will know where to start restoring by comparing the date and time of the full backup to the logs. You don't want to recommit changes that were already done in the full backup. This is my thought process.

Let's say we have this backup process:

**Full Weekly/Diff nightly/logs hourly**

For brevity's sake, I won't fill the example with tons of log backups. It should get my point across.

**Full**-**log**-**log**-**log**-**log**-Diff-**log**-**log**-**log**-**log**-Diff-**log**-**log**-**log**-**log**

Let's say I need to restore to my most current backup. What if my diffs were bad? I can still restore to any point in time because my full and logs are good. I don't need the diffs. Although my restore might take days. XD

**Full**-log-log-log-log-Diff-log-log-log-log-**Diff**-**log**-**log**-**log**-**log**

Let's say I need to restore to my most current backup. The fastest way would be to restore my full backup and then the latest Diff. Finally, I would restore all logs after the diff. I assume sql would compare the date/time of the log to the diff and reapply the correct changes. Again, logs have nothing to do with full or diffs. They are just a continuous stream/record of changes since the last log backup (independent).

Questions:

Do I understand logs correctly?

Are my restore examples correct?

If a log becomes corrupted how do I restart the log chain? Apparently, a full backup doesn't restart the log chain.

There seems to be 20 different answers online that conflict with each other. Nobody can get it straight.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/transaction-log-backups-sql-server

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2030-restarting-a-log-backup-chain-requires-a-full-database-backup/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I changed my post to better reflect my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of the logs and restore is correct for a database using FULL RECOVERY mode (which is the default). As a minor comment, SQL Server doesn't use the date/time when deciding which logs records are relevant, it uses log sequence numbers (LSNs) but the concept is the same.

To answer your last question: it's correct that a full backup doesn't invalidate the log chain, but a corrupt or missing log backup in the chain invalidates all log backups earlier than the point of failure. If a log file is corrupt your restore options are (1) the last full backup plus any diffs, or (2) if you made a full backup 'B' after the log failure you could restore the full backup 'B' and restore the subsequent log backup. Option two gives you point in time recovery to any point following 'B' as you again have an unbroken chain.

An implication of your last question is: if you have regular full backups and log backups, a corrupt log only has an effect until the next good full backup.

Disclaimer: I'm not a DBA, more of a database dev who has some interest in backup and restore and had to study this somewhat for the Microsoft MCSE.